# C# An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, installation

Good morning everyone,

I have created setup wizard for application, when I'm running application I can see data from txt files which are inside instaled folder, but when I'm trying edit data inside txt file I have got an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jean-Paul Sartre Variety Theatre\CustomerStorage.txt' is denied.

```
string text = "";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("CustomerStorage.txt");  //THAT LINE GENERATE ERROR  

foreach (var item in Customers)
{
    text = item.Value.CustomerName + "*" + item.Value.CustomerEmail + "*" + (int)item.Value.Customertype + "*" + item.Value.BookDate + "*" + item.Value.CustomerNo + "*" + item.Value.BookedPlayName + "*" + item.Value.PaymentStatus + "*" + item.Value.SeatNoOne + "*" + item.Value.SeatNoTwo + "*" + item.Value.SeatNoThree + "*" + item.Value.SeatNoFour + "*" + item.Value.SeatNoFive + "*" + item.Value.SeatNoSix + "*" + item.Value.PriceToPay + "*" + item.Value.GetPlayNo + "*" + item.Value.TotalNumberOfSeatsCustomer + "*";
    if (item.Value.Customertype == CustomerType.GoldMember)
    {
        GoldMember gm = (GoldMember)item.Value;
        //saving gold member with new created date
        gm.CreatedDate = gm.CreatedDate;
        text += gm.CreatedDate + "*";
    }
    sw.WriteLine(text);
}
sw.Close();
```

I don't know if I made any mistake during creating setup wizard and I should make someting like permission during adding txt file into file system folder.

Comment: Does your application run with the administrator permissions? By default, UAC prevents applications running without administrator permissions from writing to Program Files folder and its subfolders.
If CustomerStorage is an editable file, its better to store it somewhere in the Local App Data folder (c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\)

Comment: have you checked that your application has the write permission?

Comment: also refactor your code to wrap your `StreamWriter` object around a `using() {}` code block construct to handle / take advantage of Auto Disposing of the object..

Answer (score 0):

Grant access method sloved the problem, thanks guys.

```
public bool GrantAccess(string fullPath)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
        return true;
    }
```